# chcon: failed to change context of `/etc/oddjobd.conf.d' to `unconfined_u:object_r:oddjob_t:s0': Permission denied

Tags: linux, selinux

A friend of mine had trouble with SELinux. The server is configured with SELinux in enforcing mode, using the targeted policy.

When using Puppet, `restorecon` or `chcon`, **he had errors like this, even if SELinux was not in enforcing mode**

```
# chcon -t oddjob_t /etc/tt 
chcon: failed to change context of `/etc/oddjobd.conf.d' to `unconfined_u:object_r:oddjob_t:s0': Permission denied
```

The `/var/log/audit/audit.log` contained:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1429628369.080:338935): avc:  denied  { relabelto } for  pid=3629 comm="chcon" name="oddjobd.conf.d" dev=dm-0 ino=39413 scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:oddjob_t:s0 tclass=dir 
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1429628369.080:338935): arch=c000003e syscall=188 success=no exit=-13 a0=12f20e0 a1=3edf0162d9 a2=12f3620 a3=22 items=0 ppid=1206 pid=3629 auid=2006 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=25771 comm="chcon" exe="/usr/bin/chcon" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
```

In a similar way, `restorecon` failed:

```
# restorecon -Rv /etc 
restorecon reset /etc/oddjobd.conf.d context system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0->system_u:object_r:oddjob_t:s0 
restorecon set context /etc/oddjobd.conf.d->system_u:object_r:oddjob_t:s0 failed:'Permission denied'
```

The `/var/log/audit/audit.log` contained:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1429628361.258:338934): avc:  denied  { relabelto } for  pid=3627 comm="restorecon" name="oddjobd.conf.d" dev=dm-0 ino=39409 scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:setfiles_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:oddjob_t:s0 tclass=dir 
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1429628361.258:338934): arch=c000003e syscall=189 success=no exit=-13 a0=7fdb4b1d5190 a1=7fdb49e762d9 a2=7fdb4b1d50f0 a3=1e items=0 ppid=1206 pid=3627 auid=2006 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=25771 comm="restorecon" exe="/sbin/setfiles" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:setfiles_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
```

He was logged-in as root. The bash shell was unconfined (`id -Z`).

So what was wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Well, it turns out that my friend was just trying to use a file type which is invalid (`oddjob_t` is a process context, not a file context!)

Changing the context type of that directory to any other type was working fine (like `chcon -t etc_t /etc/oddjobd.conf.d`).

One can use `seinfo` to check which file types exists:

```
# seinfo -afile_type -x | grep "oddjob"
      oddjob_var_run_t 
      oddjob_exec_t 
      oddjob_mkhomedir_exec_t
```

Running `restorecon` was also failing because my friend had inserted an invalid file context, with:

```
semanage fcontext --add -t oddjob_t "/etc/oddjobd.conf.d(/.*)?"
```

So I removed that incorrect rule (the rule wasn't needed at all):

```
semanage fcontext --list | grep "oddjob_t"
semanage fcontext -d -t oddjob_t "/etc/oddjobd.conf.d(/.*)?"
```

P.S. I found this blog post very useful to solve this issue  [Dan Walsh's Blog: SELinux Types Revisited.](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/54803.html)